# Can anyone sketch the proof or provide a link that there is always a prime between $n^3$ and $(n+1)^3$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

In a recent forum discussion on number theory, it was mentioned that [A. E. Ingham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Ingham) had proven that there is always a prime between $n^3$ and $(n+1)^3$.

Does anyone know if there is a link available on the web or knows a rough sketch of the proof.  Does it use sieve theory?

I am very interested in checking out the proof.

Comment: Did they say when it had been proven?

Comment: It must have been a while ago.  Wikipedia reports that he died in 1967.

Comment: In Apostol's analytic number theory book, he states the theorem that there is a real number $\alpha$ such that $\lfloor\alpha^{3^n}\rfloor$ is always a prime, but that the proof is non-constructive. But this theorem would give an easy constructive method to find $\alpha$ - actually, an arbitrary number of $\alpha$s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd venture the discussion in the fora was mistaken.

As late as 2014, it appears the best is a bound on where this is true, from

[*An Explicit Result for Primes Between Cubes - A. Dudek*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.4233.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Back in the mid-80s, when I first opened Apostol's "Introduction to Analytic Number Theory," Apostol stated the theorem that there exists a real $\alpha$ such that $\left\lfloor\alpha^{3^n}\right\rfloor$ was always prime. Apostol noted, though, that the existing proof was non-constructive.

I realized relatively quickly that if you could prove there was always a prime between $n^3$ and $(n+1)^3$, you'd have an easy constructive proof.

So I highly doubt that there was a proof before 1967, when Wikipedia says Ingham died. Apostol's book was first published in 1976.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I did a Google search before posting my question and couldn't find anything.

Comment: It's certainly not a conclusive answer, but it seems unlikely. When I first read your question, I thought it might be referencing a new result, but given the death in 1967, that seems unlikely.

Comment: Ingham's proof is mentioned in HammyTheGreek's link.  See [7].

Comment: It might well be that Ingham's result is the result Apostol was referring to - that Ingham knew there were primes between consecutive cubes for sufficiently large cubes, but had no bound for "sufficiently large." @LarryFreeman

Comment: That's exactly it.  Ingham proved that there were primes for sufficiently large cubes and had no bound.  :-)